WorkManager Worker does not work after 2 or 3 days on the MIUI OS
Here is my background upload service when I am making a work request
package com.unischolarz.calllogger.utils
import android.app.Service
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.IBinder
import android.os.PowerManager
import android.util.Log
import androidx.work.Constraints
import androidx.work.NetworkType
import androidx.work.OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder
import androidx.work.WorkManager
import java.util.UUID

class BackgroundService() : Service() {

    private var wakeLock: PowerManager.WakeLock? = null

    override fun onCreate() {
        val powerManager = getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
        wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyApp::MyWakeLockTag")
        wakeLock?.acquire(10 * 60 * 1000L /*10 minutes*/)
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        if (intent == null) {
            return START_STICKY
        }

        if (intent.getBooleanExtra("ACTION", false)) {
//            performNetworkTask()
            Logger.e("networkIntent", "Inetent Received1")
        }
        return START_STICKY
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()

        wakeLock?.let {
            if (it.isHeld) {
                it.release()
            }
        }
        val broadcastIntent = Intent("ACTION.RESTART.YourService")
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent)

    }

    private fun performNetworkTask() {
        val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
            .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
            .build()

        val workRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<LogUpdateWorker>()
            .setConstraints(constraints)
            .addTag(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            .build()


        WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueue(workRequest)
        Log.d("WorkRequest", workRequest.toString())
        Log.d("MakingWrk", "Making Work")
    }

}

And here is my WorkManager
package com.unischolarz.calllogger.utils

import android.content.Context
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.util.Log
import androidx.work.CoroutineWorker
import androidx.work.Worker
import androidx.work.WorkerParameters
import com.unischolarz.calllogger.main.MainActivityViewModel

class LogUpdateWorker(private val appContext: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) :
    CoroutineWorker(appContext, workerParams) {

    private val sharedPrefs: SharedPreferences =
        appContext.getSharedPreferences("UPLOAD_PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        try {
            synchronized(this) {
                val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()

                val uploadStartTimestamp1 = sharedPrefs.getLong("UPLOAD_START_TIMESTAMP1", 0)
                if (currentTime - uploadStartTimestamp1 > MainActivityViewModel.UPLOAD_TIMEOUT) {
                    sharedPrefs.edit().putBoolean("UPLOAD_IN_PROGRESS1", false).apply()
                }

                val isUploadInProgress1 = sharedPrefs.getBoolean("UPLOAD_IN_PROGRESS1", false)

                Log.d("UPLOAD_IN_PROGRESS4", "$currentTime |||| $uploadStartTimestamp1")
                Log.d("UPLOAD_IN_PROGRESS4", "$isUploadInProgress1")

                if (!isUploadInProgress1) {
                    sharedPrefs.edit()
                        .putLong("UPLOAD_START_TIMESTAMP1", currentTime)
                        .apply()

                    Log.d("UPLOAD_IN_PROGRESS4", "INITIALIZING UPLOAD IN BACKGROUND AFTER CALL")
                    MainActivityViewModel().getAllData2(appContext)
                    Log.d("UPLOAD_IN_PROGRESS4", "UPLOAD COMPLETED IN BACKGROUND AFTER CALL")
                } else {
                    Log.d("UPLOAD_IN_PROGRESS4", "UPLOAD ALREADY IN PROGRESS")
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("UPLOAD_IN_PROGRESS4", "Exception: ${e.message}")
            logException(e)
            sharedPrefs.edit().putBoolean("UPLOAD_IN_PROGRESS1", false).apply()
            return Result.failure()
        }
        return Result.success()
    }
}

I've already taken the permission for the auto start and battery optimization, still after 2 or 3 days the WorkManger is not executing my Worker on MIUI at the same time, it works perfectly fine on Samsung devices.
I am expecting my code to work same on MIUI as it does on Samsung devices.

IT looks like you're trying to keep your service in the background at all times?  That's not going to work on any Android OS made in the last 5 or 6 years.  If you want to occasionally rrun the job in the work manager part, enqueue it as a Periodic request, not a OneTime request.

Also, there's no reason to have a wakelock here at all, or even a Service.  YOu can enqueue a WorkManager request from the Activity directly, and it will run when the conditions are right, no service needed or wanted.  Unless there's significant functionality you cut out for brevity, this is all unnecessary.
